# C++ memory stream to C file stream

Tags: c++, c, boost, stl, iostream

Given a C++ `std::istream` input memory stream, is it in any way possible to directly write data from that stream to a C file stream (`FILE*`) without having to write data to disk first?

The reason I am asking is that I have a C interface taking a `FILE*`, for which I want to transparently support either compressed or uncompressed input files.

The idea is to write a wrapper function that takes the input file, then uses `boost::iostreams` to create a filtering stream that does the decompression if necessary, then forward the decompressed data somehow to the C API.

The straightforward approach is to decompress a compressed file, write the decompressed data to disk, then `fopen` the temporary file. I want to prevent having to create temporary files though.

Another option is to decompress all data in memory, then use `fmemopen` to obtain a `FILE*` to the decompressed data. This means I might have to allocate a lot of data though, I would rather like to see a buffered solution. Is this in any way possible?

Comment: Take a look at `open_memstream`  It might do what you want.

Comment: If you want streamed/buffered data, `pipe` and `fdopen` might be better than `fmemopen`.

Comment: Does [boost::zlib](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/zlib.html) help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're on a *GNU* system, (Linux, Glibc), you can use [`fopencookie`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopencookie.3.html) to create a `FILE *` wrapper for your decoding operation:

> ```
> FILE *fopencookie(void *cookie, const char *mode, cookie_io_functions_t io_funcs);
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> The fopencookie() function serves a purpose similar to fopen(3): it
>          opens a new stream and returns a pointer to a FILE object that is
>          used to operate on that stream.
>
> The cookie argument is a pointer to the caller's cookie structure
>          that is to be associated with the new stream.  This pointer is
>          supplied as the first argument when the standard I/O library invokes
>          any of the hook functions described below.
>
> The mode argument serves the same purpose as for fopen(3).  The
>          following modes are supported: r, w, a, r+, w+, and a+.  See fopen(3)
>          for details.
>
> The io_funcs argument is a structure that contains four fields
>          pointing to the programmer-defined hook functions that are used to
>          implement this stream.  The structure is defined as follows
>
> ```
> typedef struct {
>     cookie_read_function_t  *read;
>     cookie_write_function_t *write;
>     cookie_seek_function_t  *seek;
>     cookie_close_function_t *close;
> } cookie_io_functions_t;
> ```
>
> [...]

(I didn't want to copy the *entire* manpage to my answer).

Basically then you can do:

```
ssize_t my_read(void *cookie, char *buf, size_t size) {
    std::istream *the_stream = static_cast<std::istream*>(cookie);
    // insert magic
    return bytes_read;
}

cookie_io_functions_t my_functions = {
    my_read,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
};

...

FILE *wrapped = fopencookie(static_cast<void *>&stream, "rb", my_functions);
```

On BSD/OSX, you'd be equally lucky, because it comes with [`funopen`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/funopen.3.html) which is just a slightly different API to achieve exactly the same thing.

And if you want to support Windows, well, [poor you](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/10053a26-7437-4fc4-8ac9-7e6f3308ec0c/custom-file-streams-memory-backed?forum=vclanguage).

Comment: Sorry that I did not mention this, but luckily I am on Linux :) Thanks for the answer, great solution.